# Codeigniter Cpanel Mysql Database Setup

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, smarty, cpanel

I have successfully pushed a codeigniter project to a cpanel console.
Everything seems to be working fine except the database connection.
I believe i have the settings correct but i could be wrong.
Below is my **database.php** script:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'instadri_insta',
'password' => 'BL9w;K;ds9MR',
'database' => 'instadri_ver',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
 );
```

I have the errors below:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user
>   'instadri_insta'@'localhost' to database 'instadri_ver'
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 202
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/instadri/application/controllers/Welcome.php Line: 10
>   Function: __construct
>
> File: /home/instadri/public_html/index.php Line: 319 Function:
>   require_once

I also get :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/instadri/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 568
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/instadri/application/controllers/Welcome.php Line: 10
>   Function: __construct
>
> File: /home/instadri/public_html/index.php Line: 319 Function:
>   require_once

And Finally :

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: controllers/Welcome.php
>
> Line Number: 10

I have taken care of the above.
The new issue now is the smarty template file loading.
I have a controller that does this :

```
  $this->smarty->view('front-theme/index.tpl', $data );
```

But i get this error:

> Unable to load the requested file:
>   front-theme/index.tpl

My cpanel directory structure is:

> - public_html
>         - index.php
> - application
> - system public
>      -_template
>      -_cache
>      -front-theme

Comment: Double check if db user is created. If that user is associated to that database. And if password is correctly saved. Btw. never expose credentials on public places like this.

Comment: Your host for database is likely no longer `localhost` on your hosting. Check to make sure you have the right host.

Comment: Hey guys, i fixed the issue already. Thanks.
I only have one issue left now.
My smarty isnt loading.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I have solved it.

Simply upload your CI files to the public html folder, every thing in the CI folder should be uploaded together. so when you open the public folder it should filled with the CI files.

Leave your db settings the same way, but cross-check the values you entered for validity. and finally go to the `config.php` file and check the base url variable and change to your url link name.

That's it!

Comment: i had the same problem but i have solved it, contact me for more information

Comment: I've already done it, but instead of commenting addendums to **your own post**, you should edit them in. Otherwise, nice answer.